# How to run console.log in constuctor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, constructor, console.log

As the title says, I can't run console.log from constructor. There's no compiler error. When the compiled code runs in the browser, there is nothing written in the console. No error and not "Hello World".

Here is the code:

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
}
```

When the class and constructor are removed, it works.

Comment: there is no typescript here. I suggest that you will learn javascript first.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, i need to instantiate the class!